# iTunes "Search" error

Tags: windows, search, itunes

For the past 24 hours when I type something into the "Search" window on the upper right side of iTunes and hit enter I am getting this message:

"There was a temporary problem completing your request.
The iTunes Store is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."

Everything else in iTunes is working great, I just get that message when I do a search. I can still look at all my available downloads and download them fine. I can click on any of the movies/music/tv shows and rent/purchase them. The only thing that is not working is the "Search" window. I have tried the "Search" option using multiple iTunes accounts and without being logged in at all, and the result is always the same. Also, this is only happening on a Windows server based in France that I have used for years (got a great deal on it years ago and I have used it as my primary PC ever since). Also, the iTunes "Search" window works fine on my home PC. 
Nothing was changed on the server, in fact iTunes "Search" was working fine yesterday morning but randomly stopped working yesterday evening. I made no changes to the server prior to this issue. Since the problem started, I have done full uninstalls including the registry and fresh installs, but I am still facing the same issue. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using the current version? 12.9.6.3

Second, try the following uninstall steps, followed by a Restart and then install the latest version.

To uninstall iTunes (V11, 12; Windows 7/810)

Control Panel > Programs and Features:
Uninstall the following in order as shown:

iTunes

Quick Time

Apple Software Update

Apple Mobile Device Support

Bonjour

Apple Application Support

Restart the computer.

Remove the folder:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes

Now install the latest version of iTunes

This has worked for me for times when iTunes has been troublesome

Comment: I thought the same thing (saved me a few times in the past as well). I tried it, multiple times. Followed those steps, in that order and even went into the registry to take out everything apple & itunes without success. I cleared the 'hidden' ProgramData folder of everything apple/itunes. I've tried fresh installs of older versions, as well as the current version of iTunes and they are all having the same issue. I may just have to wait until the next update and hope that solves it. Good suggestions though, thank you.